# Return a List<List<integer>>>

Tags: java, list, collections

I have to fill up the following code

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    }
}
```

So If I declare and return this
`List<List<Integer>> triples = new List<List<Integer>>();`

I get this **error:  List is abstract; cannot be instantiated**

And if i return this `List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

I get this **`error: incompatible types: ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>`**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Java-generics are invariant. Try this: `List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();` (or just use the diamond operator `<>`).

Comment: There are a lot of exactly same questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

`ArrayList` is a class that implements the `List` interface, so you can assign it to a `List` variable. The element type of the `List` - `List<Integer>` - must remain the same, since an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is not a sub-type of `List<List<Integer>>`, and therefore cannot be assigned to that variable.

After you instantiate the outer `List`, you can add `ArrayList<Integer>` instances to it:

```
trips.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Java generics are invariant:

```
List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Or, easier:

```
List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Collection that holds another Collection that holds an Integer value using

```
List<List<Integer>> trips = new ArrayList<>();
```

And if you want to get the inner list you can use this code

```
List<Integer> trip = trips.get(0);
```